# part of speech of 'total' in "...inhabit as little as one to two million acres total."

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is from [a news article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/12/magazine/can-prairie-dogs-talk.html) :

> Before 1800, as many as five billion prairie dogs lived throughout the
> Great Plains in colonies that collectively spanned more than 100
> million acres. Today, by some estimates, the five prairie-dog species
> inhabit as little as one to two million acres **total**.

I wonder what part of speech the 'total' is in this context.

Though 'total' can be used as [an adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/total#dictionary-entry-4), it doesn't mean 'in a total manner : to a total or complete degree : WHOLLY, ENTIRELY' here.

So I think 'total' here is an adjective.

Am I right?

Comment: Yup, this is a regular adjective.

Comment: @BigMistake Thank you very much.

Comment: I bet it would be analyzed as a preposition nowadays with the meaning "in total".

Comment: @TimR Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's an adjective. The word order could be slightly changed, too: "one to two million total acres.
Either way, the word suggests that those acres may not be a single large area, but the sum of all the areas occupied.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that *total* in your particular case is an adjective — instead, I will argue below that it's an adverb after all.

First of all, if *total* was an adjective, it should be possible to find other similar adjectives that could go into the same slot in your sentence. But let's try with some of the [synonymous adjectives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/total#synonyms) suggested by Merriam-Webster for *total* (note that I only chose synonyms that aren't listed as adverbs to avoid the same ambiguity as we have with *total*):

> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **absolute***
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **complete***
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **unconditional***
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **utter***

None of these sentences appear to be grammatical with the adjective after *acres* — but they would be grammatical if the adjectives preceded *acres* (even if the meaning might be somewhat obscure):

> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million **absolute** acres*
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million **complete** acres*
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million **unconditional** acres*
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million **utter** acres*

This observation is important because one of the other answers uses the fact that *total* can move to this attributive position in front of *acres* as an argument that *total* in the sentence-final position has to be an adjective as well. But if that's really true — why can't the other adjectives moved to the sentence-final position as well?

One easy explanation would be this: *total* can be used both as an adjective and an adverb, but *absolute*, *complete*, *unconditional*, and *utter* aren't used as adverbs, only as adjectives. As the latter can't occur in the position after *acres*, but the former can, this slot may be reserved for adverbs, but blocked for adjectives.

We can test this explanation by trying out some synonyms of *total* that are also used both as adjectives and adverbs:

> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **all-out***
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **downright***
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **flat***
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit as little as one to two million acres **thorough***

To be honest, I'm not really happy with all of these examples, but at least *flat* and to some degree, *all-out* seem kind of okay to me — much more so than all the examples above with *absolute*, *complete*, *unconditional*, and *utter* which I'd just reject as ungrammatical.

This test, then, seems to support my hypothesis that *total* is an adverb. But you don't have to agree with this deduction — there's also support in the literature, specifically in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL, 2002). But we'll need to do a small structural analysis of your sentence first. Regardless of whether it's an adjective or adverb, it's clear that *alone* is part of the noun phrase that acts as the object to *inhabit*:

> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [*as little as one to two million acres total*]

We know this since we can replace the whole group of words by a single pronoun such as *this* or *them*, and we can turn the words into the subject of a passive sentence:

> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [***this***]
>
> [***as little as one to two million acres total***] *are inhabited by the five prairie-dog species*

But that's not all: this noun phrase contains another noun phrase [*one to two million acres*] in a nested structure, like so: [*as little as* [*one to two million acres*] *total*] (we know this because again, we could substitute *one to two million acres* by a pronoun:

> the five prairie-dog species inhabit [*as little as* [***this***] *total*]

So, what we're dealing with is what CGEL calls a noun phrase with external modifiers, i.e. with two elements that flank the noun phrase to the left (*as little as*) and to the right (*total*) to form a new, more complex noun phrase.

More to the point, CGEL analyses *total* as a "peripheral modifier" (CGEL, ch. 5.2), and it provides a list of three forms that can occur in this particular position: (1) adverbs, (2) prepositional phrases, (3) reflexive pronouns. Here are modifications of your sentence that illustrate each type (although admittedly, the last one is a bit weird):

1. **Adverb**: *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [*as little as one to two million acres **too***]
2. **Prepositional phrases**: *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [*as little as one to two million acres **across the board***]
3. **Reflexives**: *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [*as little as one of two million acres **themselves***]

Notably, adjectives are not considered by CGEL as peripheral modifiers, which agrees with our test using synonymous unambiguous adjectives above, and which seems to be fair if we look at adjective-adverb pairs that are morphologically distinct such as *true*/*truly*:

> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [*as little as one to two million acres **true***] ← NOT POSSIBLE
>
> *the five prairie-dog species inhabit* [*as little as one to two million acres **truly***] ← POSSIBLE

**TL;DR:**

So, to conclude: Since *total* can be an adverb (as supported by your [Merriam-Webster link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/total#dictionary-entry-4)), since it's been argued (by CGEL) that adverbs (but not adjectives) can be used as peripheral modifiers, and since *total* behaves differently from other synonymous adjectives that cannot be mistaken as adverbs, it seems to me that the most plausible interpretation is that *total* is an adverb after all.

Comment: Thank you very much.